# Javascript "classes" - am i heading the right way?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

In the past couple of years I've returned part time to programming after a 15 year gap. I was C/UNIX. So, I've picked up PHP, Java, C++ ok, but have struggled with Javascript.

Finally I think I've found a way to 'create' classes that can inherit and wondered if anyone would care to comment. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function Base( options ) {
    var that = this;
    options = options || {};
    Object.keys( options ).forEach( function( item ) {
        that[item] = options[item];
    });
}

function Creature( options ) {
    this.legs = 4;

    Base.call( this, options );
    console.log("New creature");
}

Creature.prototype.showNumberOfLegs = function() {
    console.log( "Number legs " + this.legs );
};


function Mammal( options ) {
    this.fur = true;
    Creature.call( this, options );

    console.log("New mammal");
}

Mammal.prototype = Object.create( Creature.prototype );

Mammal.prototype.showFur = function() {
    console.log( "Fur " + this.fur );
};

var c = new Creature();
c.showNumberOfLegs();

var m = new Mammal({ legs: 6, fur: false });
m.showNumberOfLegs();
m.showFur();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated
Mini

Comment: You might consider posting this question to code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks @OddDev, I've done that

Comment: this'll bring back memories: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking